# Error 1180 Call to possibly undefined method Bullet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a problem here and I have tried my best to figure out why I'm getting this error on Line 325. Here is the entire script. I'm using Flash CS5.5. Thank you for helping as I'm completely stuck. I changed the names of my movieClips but still the error persists. Thanks again.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var file:URLRequest = new URLRequest("vermin-ator.swf");
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteLoad);

loader.load(file);

function onCompleteLoad (loadEvent:Event):void
{
    addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}





        // player settings      
         var _rotateSpeedMax:Number = 20;
        //private var _gravity:Number = .68;

        // projectile gun settings
         var _bulletSpeed:Number = 8;       
         var _maxDistance:Number = 300;
         var _reloadSpeed:Number = 250; //milliseconds
         var _barrelLength:Number = 20;
         var _bulletSpread:Number = 5;
         var score:int = 0;

        // gun stuff - do not edit
         var _isLoaded:Boolean = true;      
         var _isFiring:Boolean = false;
         var _endX:Number;
         var _endY:Number;
         var _startX:Number;
         var _startY:Number;
         var _reloadTimer:Timer;
         var _bullets:Array = [];

        // array that holds walls
         //var _solidObjects:Array = [];
         //array for rifle sounds
         var mySoundArray:Array = [];
         var mySoundRandom:Number;

         //game scorings
         //var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        // myFormat.size = 20;
         //var gameScoreField:TextField;

         //var gameScore:int;
        // gameScore = 0;
        // var myText_txt:TextField = new TextField();

        // global vars
         var player:MovieClip;
         //var _player2:MovieClip;
         //var _player3:MovieClip;
         var _dx:Number;
         var _dy:Number;
         var _pcos:Number;
         var _psin:Number;
         var _trueRotation:Number;
         var count:Number;

         var dougie:MovieClip;
         var murphy:MovieClip;
         var dougieTalk:MovieClip;
         var murphyTalk:MovieClip;
         var murphyScream:MovieClip;
         var newRabbit:MovieClip;
         var tempBullet:MovieClip;
         var bullet_mc:MovieClip;

        //how much time before another rabbit is made
        var rabbitTime:int = 0;
        //how much time is needed to make a rabbit
        var rabbitLimit:int = 16;
        //this movieclip holds the bullets
        //var bulletContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        //addChild(bulletContainer)

        var soundOn:Boolean = true;
        //var myTransform:SoundTransform;

    //variable for rifle sound
    var rifle1Sound:Sound = new rifle1sound();
    //variable for rifle sound
    var rifle2Sound:Sound = new rifle2sound();
    //variable for rifle sound
    var rifle3Sound:Sound = new rifle3sound();
    //variable for rifle sound
    var rifle4Sound:Sound = new rifle4sound();

    //variable for man laughing
    //var manLaughSound:Sound = new manlaughsound();
    //variable for man laughing
    //var manPleasedSound:Sound = new manpleasedsound();
    //varible for background sound
    var bckgroundSound:Sound = new bckgroundsound();
    //varible for rabbit shot sound
    //var rabbitSound:Sound = new rabbitsound();
    //variable for button sound
    var BtnSound:Sound = new buttonSound();




    //make screen for Stop invisible
    var stopScreen:MovieClip;
    //make screen for Credits visible
    var creditScreen:MovieClip;
    //make screen for Rules visible
    var rulesScreen:MovieClip;

    murphyTalk.visible = true;
    dougieTalk.visible = true;
    dougie.visible = true;
    murphy.visible = true;
    murphyScream.visible = true;
    creditScreen.visible = true;
    rulesScreen.visible = true;
    stopScreen.visible = false;


    //enable hand cursors on mouse over over buttons
    var movieClip_8:MovieClip;
    var movieClip_9:MovieClip;
    var movieClip_10:MovieClip;
    var movieClip_11:MovieClip;
    var newrabbit:MovieClip;
    var closeGame:MovieClip;

    //listener and function for how to play button
movieClip_10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, helpScreen);
function helpScreen(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    rulesScreen.visible=true;
}

        //listener and function for how to play button
movieClip_9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ahelpScreen);
function ahelpScreen(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    creditScreen.visible=true;
}
    //Add event listeners for all 3 Over, Out and Down
    movieClip_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
    function mOver(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    murphyTalk.visible = false;
    dougieTalk.visible = false;
    dougie.visible = false;
    murphy.visible = false;
    murphyScream.visible= true;

    }
    movieClip_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);

//Mouse methods
function mOut(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    murphyScream.visible= false;
    removeChild(murphyTalk);
    removeChild(dougieTalk);
    removeChild(dougie);
    removeChild(murphy);

     //Remove all listeners
movieClip_8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
movieClip_8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);



    }


        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        //public function Main() 

        /*recurring event listener for updates
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showGameScore);
    function showGameScore() {
    gameScoreField.text = "Game: "+String(gameScore);
    addChild(gameScoreField); */
movieClip_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown); 
function mDown(e:MouseEvent):void { 

    createPlayer();

            // add listeners
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, `enter code here`onMouseDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUpHandler);

            // add movieclips to solidObjects array
            // will test for collisions with bullets
            //
            // *** movieclips are located on stage in the fla
            //_solidObjects = [rabbit01, rabbit02, rabbit03, rabbit04];
            //adding enemies to stage
    if(rabbitTime < rabbitLimit){
    //if time hasn't reached the limit, then just increment
    rabbitTime ++;
        } else {
    //defining a variable which will hold the new enemy
    //var newRabbit:MovieClip = new Rabbit();
    //making the enemy offstage when it is created
    newrabbit.s = -1 * newrabbit.width;
    //making the enemy's x coordinates random
    //the "int" function will act the same as Math.floor but a bit faster
    newrabbit.x = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - newrabbit.width));
    //then add the enemy to stage
    addChild(newrabbit);
    //and reset the enemyTime
    rabbitTime = 0;
}


        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Player & Weapon Methods
        //////////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * Creates player
         * Uses "Player" movieclip linked in library
         */
        function createPlayer():void
        {
            // attach player movieclip from library
            player = new Player();

            // position player in center
            player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            //_player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

            // add to display list
            stage.addChild(player);
        }



        /**
         * Reload timer
         * @param   e   Takes TimerEvent
         */
        function reloadTimerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void 
        {
            // stop timer
            e.target.stop();

            // clear timer var
            _reloadTimer = null;

            reloadWeapon();
        }


        /**
         * Fire weapon
         */
         function fire():void
        {
            // check if firing
            if (!_isFiring) return;

            // check if reloaded
            if (!_isLoaded) return;

            // create bullet
            createBullet();

            // start reload timer
            _reloadTimer = new Timer(_reloadSpeed);
            _reloadTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, `enter code here`reloadTimerHandler);
            _reloadTimer.start();

            // set reload flag to false
            _isLoaded = false;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a bullet movieclip and sets it's properties
         */
        function createBullet():void
        {
            // precalculate the cos & sine
            _pcos = Math.cos(player.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
            _psin = Math.sin(player.rotation * Math.PI / 180);

            // start X & Y
            // calculate the tip of the barrel
            _startX = player.x - _barrelLength * _pcos;
            _startY = player.y - _barrelLength * _psin;

            // end X & Y
            // calculate where the bullet needs to go
            // aim 50 pixels in front of the gun
            _endX = player.x - 50 * _pcos + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - `enter code here`_bulletSpread * .5;
            _endY = player.y - 50 * _psin + Math.random() * _bulletSpread - `enter code here`_bulletSpread * .5;

            // attach bullet from library
            var tempBullets:MovieClip = new Bullet();

            // calculate velocity
            tempBullets.vx = (_endX - _startX) / _bulletSpeed;
            tempBullets.vy = (_endY - _startY) / _bulletSpeed;

            // set position
            tempBullets.x = _startX;
            tempBullets.y = _startY;

            // save starting location
            tempBullets.startX = _startX;
            tempBullets.startY = _startY;

            // set maximum allowed travel distance
            tempBullets.maxDistance = _maxDistance;

            // add bullet to bullets array
            _bullets.push(tempBullets);

            // add to display list
            stage.addChild(tempBullets);
        }

        /**
         * Updates bullets
         */
        function updateBullets():void
        {
            var i:int;
            var tempBullets:MovieClip;

            // loop thru _bullets array
            for (i = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++)
            {
                // save a reference to current bullet
                tempBullets = _bullets[i];

                // check if gravity is enabled
                //if (gravityCheckbox.selected)
                //{
                    // add gravity to Y velocity
                    //tempBullet.vy += _gravity;
                }

                // update bullet position
                tempBullets.x += tempBullets.vx;
                tempBullets.y += tempBullets.vy;

                // check if bullet went too far
                if (getDistance(tempBullets.startX - tempBullets.x, `enter code here`tempBullets.startY - tempBullets.y) > tempBullets.maxDistance + `enter code here`_barrelLength)
                {
                    destroyBullet(tempBullets);
                }

                // check for collision with walls
                if (checkCollisions(tempBullets.x, tempBullets.y))
                {
                    destroyBullet(tempBullets);
                }

        }

        /**
         * Destroys bullet
         * @param   bullet  Takes bullet movieclip
         */
         function destroyBullet(bullet_mc:MovieClip):void
        {
            var i:int;
            var tempBullets:MovieClip;

            // loop thru _bullets array
            for (i = 0; i < _bullets.length; i++)
            {
                // save a reference to current bullet
                tempBullets = _bullets[i];

                // if found bullet in array
                if (tempBullets == bullet_mc)
                {
                    // remove from array
                    _bullets.splice(i, 1);

                    // remove from display list
                    _bullets.removeChild(bullet_mc);

                    // stop loop
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Reload weapon
         */
        function reloadWeapon():void
        {
            _isLoaded = true;
        }

        /**
         * Checks for collisions between points and objects in _solidObjects
         * @return  Collision boolean
         */
         function checkCollisions(testX:Number, testY:Number):Boolean
        {
            //var i:int;
            var newrabbit:MovieClip;

            // loop thru _solidObjects array
            //for (i = 0; i < _solidObjects.length; i++)
            {
                // save a reference to current object
                //newRabbit = _solidObjects[i];

                // do a hit test
                if (newrabbit.hitTestPoint(testX, testY, true))
                {

                    return true;


                    // stop loop
                    //break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


        /**checking if Rabbits is touching any bullets

        for(var i:int = 0;i<_root.bulletContainer.numChildren;i++){
    //numChildren is the amount of movieclips within the bulletContainer.

    //we define a variable that will be the bullet that we are currently
    //hit testing.
    var bulletTarget:MovieClip = _root.bulletContainer.getChildAt(i);

    //now we hit test
    if(hitTestObject(bulletTarget)){
        //remove this from the stage if it touches a bullet
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        _root.removeChild(this);
        //also remove the bullet and its listeners
        _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
        bulletTarget.removeListeners();
    }
}*/



        /**
         * Calculate player rotation 
         */
        function updateRotation():void
        {
            // calculate rotation based on mouse X & Y
            _dx = player.x - stage.mouseX;
            _dy = player.y - stage.mouseY;

            // which way to rotate
            var rotateTo:Number = getDegrees(getRadians(_dx, _dy)); 

            // keep rotation positive, between 0 and 360 degrees
            if (rotateTo > player.rotation + 90) rotateTo -= 180;
            if (rotateTo < player.rotation - 90) rotateTo += 180;

            // ease rotation
            _trueRotation = (rotateTo - player.rotation) / _rotateSpeedMax;

            // update rotation
            player.rotation += _trueRotation;           
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Event Handlers
        //////////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * Enter Frame handler
         * @param   event   Uses Event
         */
        function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            updateRotation();
            updateBullets();
            fire();


        }
        /**
         * Mouse Up handler
         * @param   e   Uses MouseEvent
         */
        function onMouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            _isFiring = false;
            //make bubble for Run Scream invisible
            murphyScream.visible = false;
        }

        /**
         * Mouse Down handler
         * @param   e   Uses MouseEvent
         */
         function onMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            _isFiring = true;

            //play random rifle sound from an array
            var mySoundArray:Array = new Array(rifle1sound, rifle2sound, `enter code here`rifle3sound, rifle4sound);
            `enter code here`mySoundArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*mySoundArray.length)].play();
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Utilities
        //////////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * Get distance
         * @param   delta_x
         * @param   delta_y
         * @return
         */
        function getDistance(delta_x:Number, delta_y:Number):Number
        {
            return Math.sqrt((delta_x*delta_x)+(delta_y*delta_y));
        }

        /**
         * Get radians
         * @param   delta_x
         * @param   delta_y
         * @return
         */
         function getRadians(delta_x:Number, delta_y:Number):Number
        {
            var r:Number = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

            if (delta_y < 0)
            {
                r += (2 * Math.PI);
            }
            return r;
        }

        /**
         * Get degrees
         * @param   radians Takes radians
         * @return  Returns degrees
         */
        function getDegrees(radians:Number):Number
        {
            return Math.floor(radians/(Math.PI/180));


    }

    movieClip_8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);



}

        //listener and function for how to play button
    movieClip_11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, bhelpScreen);
    function bhelpScreen(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    stopScreen.visible=true;


        }
closeGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, closeApp);

function closeApp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fscommand("quit");

}
```

Comment: Is the AS Linkage in the library for your bullet movie clip spelled correctly?

Comment: Hi Cristina.  I checked I noticed I had the var tempBullet but it in the library it's tempBullets. Well, I changed that but still getting the 1180 error.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you want the class name to be "Bullet" in the library

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that did clear it up, but a good other errors I'm dealing with now...oh poor me lol.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Bullet is also the class name on the library.